# Email send issue in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, email, smtp, laravel-5.1

I am using laravel 5.1 and i'm trying to send email from laravel application from localhost.

I have been configure my Email Credentials in .env file But, i'm getting **Authentication required** Error.
I'm attaching code of **.env** file and controller file.

**.env**

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=1MJzLfnALmtppcbfzoVtlf8rzsFX94nm

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=real_estate
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=''

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=my_account@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=my_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

**Controller code**

```
$subject = 'Welcome!';
    Mail::send('mail', ['key' => 'value'], function($message) use ($subject) {
    // note: if you don't set this, it will use the defaults from config/mail.php
    $message->from('my_account@gmail.com', 'Sender Name');
    $message->to('receiver_account@gmail.com', 'John Smith')
            ->subject($subject);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code itself looks fine, however in your `.env` file the encryption should be `tls` not `ssl`; i.e

`MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`

The other thing to double check is whether your Google account is set to allow the use of less secure apps. If it isn't then this could cause issues for you, but just go to your Google account homepage and follow: Sign-in & security -> Connected apps & sites -> Allow less secure apps

https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps

Just turn this on and you'll be good to go.

If not, then check out [this link](http://learninglaravel.net/learn-to-send-emails-using-gmail-and-sendgrid-in-laravel-5) and at the bottom of the article there are some ideas you can try.